# switch case without variable

Tags: java, switch-statement, case

Is it possible to write switch case code without specifying a variable in switch? say I have two variables int x and int y. I want to conditionally run code based on different combinations of x and y. For example

```
switch
{
    case (x==1 && y==1): //do something.
        break;
    case (x==3 && y==-1): //do something.
        break;
    case (x==0 && y==3): //do something.
        break;
    default: //do something.
        break;
}
```

This code gives me error.

Comment: If I were to support such a code, I'd curse you :)

Answer (score 4):

Keep the switch parameter as ture

```
switch(true)
{
    case (x==1 && y==1): //do something.
        break;
    case (x==3 && y==-1): //do something.
        break;
    case (x==0 && y==3): //do something.
        break;
    default: //do something.
        break;
}
```

Comment: This is the only answer that truly addresses the question. Other answers suggest _it's not possible with switch case._

Comment: It's not okey that use a not usable condition in the switch-case statement, and in this case you have to se if-else statement

Answer (score 3):

That doesn't really read or write better than

```
if (x==1 && y==1) {
    //do something.
}
else if (x==3 && y==-1) {
    //do something.
}
else if (x==0 && y==3) {
    //do something.
}
else {
    //do something.
}
```

But yea, it's not possible with switch case.

Comment: It is possible with `switch`. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59172196/3429430

Answer (score 3):

You can better use a `if-else` for your problem

Answer (score 0):

In switch case you can't use == use only values. For your condition use if else.

Answer (score 0):

The **obvious** way is to use `else if`:

```
if (x==1 && y==1) {
    //do something.
}
else if (x==3 && y==-1) {
    //do something.
}
else if (x==0 && y==3) {
    //do something.
}
else {
   // do something as default case.
}
```

One variant is to use a **separate method**.

The benefit is that you can then use `return`.

```
if (x==1 && y==1) {
    //do something.
    return;
}
// precompute something...
if (x==3 && y==-1) {
    //do something.
    return;
}
if (x==0 && y==3) {
    //do something.
    return;
}
// do something as default case.
return;
```

but it doesn't make a huge difference unless you have *nested `else` branches*.

But **the one case where `case` actually has benefits over `if else`** is when you have a **complete enumeration of cases**. It avoids *programming errors* then:

```
switch(direction) {
  case NORTH: // Do something
    break;
  case SOUTH: // Do something
    break;
  case EAST: // Do something
    break;
  case WEST: // Do something
    break;
}
```

the nice thing is that the compiler can actually check that you don't need a `default` branch.

Unless you have a **complete enumeration**, `if` is just as good.

Comment: That's not an answer to the question if the switch can be used that way.

Answer (score -1):

The whole point of [`switch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) is to do something based on the value of a *single* variable and, moreover, to only test for equality. In your case you could use a series of `else-if`s.

```
if (x==1 && y==1) {
    // do something
} else if (x==3 && y==-1) {
    // do something
} else if (x==0 && y==3) {
    // do something
} else {
    // do something (default)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Hwre is syntax of switch case**

```
switch ( expression ) statement
labeled-statement:
case constant-expression : statement
default : statement
```

it is clearly shown that you have to pass
expression in **switch(exp)**
so you can't leave it.